# Azure blob batch delete cyrillic characters

Tags: c#, azure, blob

I am able to upload blobs containing cyrillic characters using `Azure.Storage.Blobs 12.9.1` but then am unable to batch delete them using `Azure.Storage.Blobs.Batch 12.6.0`.

Consider the following blob name: здраве-и-красота-от-природатаjpg--xfgqfvhj.axp.webp
and code:

```
var blobsToBeDeleted = new List<Uri>();
blobsToBeDeleted.Add(new Uri("azure-storage-address/container/здраве-и-красота-от-природатаjpg--xfgqfvhj.axp.webp"));
blobsToBeDeleted.Add(new Uri("azure-storage-address/container/thumbs/здраве-и-красота-от-природатаjpg--xfgqfvhj.axp.webp"));
await batchClient.DeleteBlobsAsync(blobsToBeDeleted);
```

After running this against Azure the response is:

```
Azure.RequestFailedException
{"Invalid response\r\nStatus: 202 (Accepted)\r\n\r\nHeaders:\r\nTransfer-Encoding: chunked\r\nServer: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0,Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0\r\nx-ms-request-id: 9255671d-301e-008e-1a4a-797e59000000\r\nx-ms-version: 2020-08-04\r\nx-ms-client-request-id: ad39b21f-aad7-484e-8121-a707a318088e\r\nDate: Thu, 15 Jul 2021 07:24:29 GMT\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=batchresponse_7c0d302a-8ee6-4d48-aac1-d973904338c3\r\n"}  Azure.RequestFailedException
{"Expected 2 responses for the batch request, not 1."}
Status 202
```

Other files having the name structure and using the same code as above, but containing only latin characters are deleted successfully.

`new Uri()` seems to properly escape characters and since the `BlobBatchClient.DeleteBlobsAsync` method accepts `IEnumerable<Uri>` I really don't understand where is the problem.

Any ideas on this?

*EDIT*

This is a know issue, already fixed and will be released in the next version - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/22329

Comment: Seems like a bug, maybe worth taking to github

Comment: Yep, just created a new issue in GitHub. Leaving it here for reference - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/22671

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try something like the following. It is a bit convoluted approach and the SDK can certainly be improved but it works:

```
private static string connectionString =
    "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=account-name;AccountKey=account-key==";
private static string containerName = "container-name";

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
    BlobBatchClient batchClient = new BlobBatchClient(blobServiceClient);
    
    List<string> blobNames = new List<string>()
    {
        "здраве-и-красота-от-природатаjpg--xfgqfvhj.axp.webp",
        "thumbs/здраве-и-красота-от-природатаjpg--xfgqfvhj.axp.webp"
    };
    BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
    List<BlobClient> blobClients = blobNames.Select(b => containerClient.GetBlobClient(b)).ToList();
    List<Uri> blobsToBeDeleted = blobClients.Select(b => new Uri(Uri.EscapeUriString(b.Uri.AbsoluteUri))).ToList();
    await batchClient.DeleteBlobsAsync(blobsToBeDeleted);
}
```

**UPDATE**

So I had a need to implement this functionality in a project of mine and I found an alternate way to implement this functionality which is somewhat less convoluted. I thought I would share that as well here. Here's the code I ended up implementing:

```
private static string connectionString =
    "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=account-name;AccountKey=account-key==";
private static string containerName = "container-name";
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
    BlobBatchClient batchClient = new BlobBatchClient(blobServiceClient);
    
    List<string> blobNames = new List<string>()
    {
        HttpUtility.UrlEncode("здраве-и-красота-от-природатаjpg--xfgqfvhj.axp.pdf"),
        HttpUtility.UrlEncode("здраве-и-красота-от-природатаjpg--xfgqfvhj.pdf")
    };
    BlobBatch batch = new BlobBatch(batchClient);
    foreach (var blobName in blobNames)
    {
        batch.DeleteBlob(containerName, blobName, DeleteSnapshotsOption.IncludeSnapshots);
    }

    await batchClient.SubmitBatchAsync(batch);
}
```

Comment: Just tested and confirming this approach works fine. It's really a bit overwhelming but does the job. Other solution would be to use the regular DeleteBlobAsync() method which accepts a regular string and works as expected.

Comment: `It's really a bit overwhelming` - That's an understatement :). SDK can most certainly be improved considering the [`REST API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-batch#request-body) only expects the partial path (container name + blob name).

Comment: I really appreciate your answer because this was causing issues for a while in our application. And I am impressed nobody opened an issue for this since now :)

Comment: @IvayloDimitrov - Updated my answer with somewhat cleaner approach. HTH.